# Loop and match test in a request MySQL passed in java

Tags: java, mysql

I search to make this request without functions :

For an id `list of a table A of equipments`,

If this id A is in a correspondence table B match with an id C, return a specific value in the `table C of equipments` at the line of the id C.

Else `return 0`.

In brief, how can I put a loop `MySQL` with a match correspondence which return a specific value if matching, else return 0.

Comment: How much do you know about SQL? Have you heard of "JOIN", "SELECT" and "WHERE" ?

Comment: I wasn't sure because it sounds like that is what you need. You need to join A and B on id, then select from that resulting table where id is C. Something like "SELECT * FROM A RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id WHERE A.id = C". Or at least something very similar.